# Statement of Chow's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Chow's theorem states that an analytic subspace X of complex projective space $\mathbb{P}_r(\mathbb{C})$ that is closed in the topology defined by an analytic subspace is an algebraic subvariety.

My understanding of an algebraic subvariety is that defined in Serre's FAC page 4 section 34: http://achinger.impan.pl/fac/fac.pdf.

Part of the definition requires that there be a finite open cover of X = {$U_i$} such that each $U_i$ is biregularly isomorphic with $V_i \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and $V_i$ being an intersection of a Zariski closed and Zariski open set.

If X is proven Zariski-closed in $\mathbb{P}_r(\mathbb{C})$ why is it an algebraic variety? Maybe this is obvious and we can let the finite cover be {X}, but I still don't understand why it should be isomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Please clear up the confusion, thank you.

Comment: the finite cover is $X \cap D(x_i)$ where $\mathbb{P}^r(\mathbb{C}) = \bigcup_{i = 0}^r D(x_i)$ is the standard affine cover of projective space -- look up this cover if you haven't seen it before.

Comment: I assume you are making reference to page 10 of Hartshorne with the $\phi_i$ regular maps. Why should $\phi_i(X \cap D(x_i))$ be an intersection of a Zariski closed and a Zariski open set?... btw$\phi$ is supposed to be a homeomorphism. Is its inverse $\phi^-1$ also regular? I presume it should be anyways. Does a homeomorphism preserve locally closed sets (intersections of Z-open and Z-closed sets) and not just strictly Z-open only and Z-closed only sets? I am a bit confused...

Comment: **1.** Can you clarify your first question? Are you asking if it is enough to show Z-closedness for a space to be an algebraic variety?

**2.** You can't take the finite cover to be $\{X\}$ because each element of the cover is required to be a Z-locally closed subspace of an *affine* space, and $X$ isn't necessarily one [p. 41, FAC].

Comment: As to your comment, the $\phi_i$ are charts, i.e., homeomorphisms. So, as an open mapping, each $\phi_i$ preserves locally closed sets.

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192876/hartshorne-corollary-2-3-question-which-topology. we can reduce to the other post with Y=X (Zariski-closed subset of $\mathbb{P}_n(\mathbb{C})$)... you might have to assume irreducibility.